# How to pass in a selector string to a jQuery event listener using the object syntax

Tags: jquery, event-listener

I'm using the following object syntax for jQuery's [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) listener.

```
$(window).on({
    keydown: function(event){
    },
});
```

Using this syntax, how can I achieve the following

```
$(window).on("keydown", "div", function(event){
});
```

I'd like to use the former syntax, and pass in a selector string to filter the descendants. Sounds like a very basic question, but I couldn't find any examples in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data  If you look at the second option that shows the form you use, the descendent filter is the second argument

Comment: @Taplar But in the syntax I use, I pass in a single object as an argument, Hence the confusion.

Comment: `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ] )` is the second option, and the details of events for that one is *An object in which the string keys represent one or more space-separated event types and optional namespaces, and the values represent a handler function to be called for the event(s).*, which is what you are doing.

Comment: @Taplar apologies for not reading carefully, you're right. If you'd like to add an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Nah, I just pointed out the details in the api, :)

Comment: Mav - If you prefer, I can delete my answer, which lets you delete the question. But I haven't seen the question before, so it may be useful to others in the future. @Taplar - Because it may be useful to others, if you want to post it as an answer, I'm happy to delete mine in favor of yours. I came to the question later and misunderstood your comment on first read, then checked the docs and wrote an answer, then realized I'd come to the same place you already had. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's all good.  The information is here and your answer covers it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still pass the delegation selector as a second argument (see [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data)). It applies to **all** of the events:

```
$(window).on(
    {
        keydown: function(event){
        },
        anotherEvent: function(event) {
        },
        someOtherEvent: function(event) {
        },
    },
    "div"
);
```

You can't hook up multiple event handlers with *different* delegation selectors in a single `on` call. If you need to do that, you need multiple calls:

```
$(window)
    .on("keydown", "div", function(event){
    })
    .on("anotherEvent", "span", function(event) {
    })
    .on("someOtherEvent", "p", function(event) {
    });
```